# Can I use OSB in place of timber as structural element

Tags: particle-board

In few answers I've been advised to reinforce OSB shelf with wooden beam for rigidity over time. Hence interconnected questions:

1. Isn't OSB supposed to be more stable to elements comparing to wood? Isn't that what's all the adhesive in it is for.
2. Tables give me tensile strength of OSB few times smaller than wood. Can I replace 18mm x 36mm wooden beam safely with 2* 50mm strips of 22mm OSB screwed and/or glued together? That'd give me 50x44 "beam" section -- should be quite enough.
3. Should OSB surface and edges be treated if I plan indoor use with no proximity of water. For it's tensile characteristics to remain same over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, it's more stable, but not to "the elements". While it is constructed with exterior-grade adhesive, the nature of thinly-shaved wood means that when exposed to moisture, repeated flex, etc. it tends to break down sooner than high-quality, solid wood. It's certainly more flat and stable than conventional plywood when kept dry.
2. OSB is less stiff than solid lumber in a horizontal orientation, but it is roughly as strong. You'll probably be able to carry the same load with an equivalent dimension, but it may sag more. Floor joists are commonly built with OSB vertical members, but the wood strands are oriented vertically. In your case, they'd be horizontal. Therein lies the difference.
3. No, though you could run a router or sander over them to reduce abrasion. They'll scuff skin in a hurry. When I use OSB for shelving I run a 1/2" bullnose router down the edges.

Comment: great answer,I use a piece of trim and cut bullnose on the leading edge helps reduce the sag and covers the rough edge.(This creates a small lip on the bottom side of the shelf the way I do it)